# Bash grep array as pattern, thinks it's a file

Tags: bash, heroku, grep, heroku-cli

I'm using Heroku cli to pull a list of backups from Heroku. I'm only looking to grab those that have scheduled backups (`heroku pg:backups:schedules`), but the only way to get their ID is through `heroku pg:backups` which prints everything. I'm trying to use grep to cut up the output and only give me a list of IDs for ones I need.

My thought is that I should be able to use the array list of backup names I need and grep it against the full list of backups. However, grep either doesn't like the iteration of the array (`array[0]`) or thinks I'm passing it a file name.

```
for (( x=0; x<DB_COUNT; x++ ))
do
    BACKUP_NAMES[($x)]=$(heroku pg:backups:schedules -a $APP_NAME | sed -n '1!p' | cut -f1 -d":")
    BACKUP_IDS[($x)]=$(heroku pg:backups -a $APP_NAME | grep '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]*' | grep -w $BACKUP_NAMES)
done
```

I've tried `grep -w ${BACKUP_NAMES[$x]}` `grep -w "$BACKUP_NAMES[$x]"` `grep -w "$BACKUP_NAMES"` and a thousand others but I either get a syntax error or grep thinks $BACKUP_NAMES is a file instead of a pattern. I've been trying to figure this out for hours and I'm just completely stumped.

EDIT:

`BACKUP_NAMES` contains `DATABASE_NAME DATABASE_NAME2`

Output of `heroku pg:backups`

```
=== Backups
ID    Created at                Status                              Size     Database
a555 2020-01-09 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-09 07:30:08 +0000 1.16GB DATABASE_NAME
a554 2020-01-08 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-08 07:30:08 +0000 5.93GB DATABASE_NAME2
a553 2020-01-07 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-07 07:30:08 +0000 1.16GB DATABASE_NAME3
a552 2020-01-06 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-06 07:30:08 +0000 5.89GB DATABASE_NAME4
a551 2020-01-05 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-05 07:30:08 +0000 3.21GB DATABASE_NAME5
a550 2020-01-04 07:26:21 +0000 Completed 2020-01-04 07:30:08 +0000 1.16GB DATABASE_NAME6
```

Output of `heroku pg:backups:schedules`

```
=== Backup Schedules
DATABASE_NAME: daily at 5:00 UTC
DATABASE_NAME2: daily at 7:00 UTC
```

Comment: By default `grep` takes a single regular expression to search for. What exactly is in the `BACKUP_NAMES` (i.e. the output of `heroku pg:backups:schedules`)? I presume it's something like a list of backup names separated by newlines? Can the names contain any shell or regex metacharacters (spaces, asterisks, question marks, square-brackets, ...)?

Comment: Can you include the output of the commands so we can try it even without heroku installed?

Comment: I edited to answer your questions. The names never contain any metacharacters.

Comment: From where the variable `DB_COUNT` come? The counter `x` seems meaningless in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the loop? I think you can capture the backup names in one variable including the newlines and use that in process substitution as a parameter to `grep -w -f`:

```
backup_names=$(heroku pg:backups:schedules -a $APP_NAME | sed -n '1!p' | cut -f1 -d":")
heroku pg:backups -a $APP_NAME | grep -w -f <(echo "$backup_names")
```

I also removed the `grep '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'` as it didn't change the output for the data you provided.

Comment: I'm looking to assign an array to the list of backup IDs, as @tshiono said in their answer. It must be in the same order as backup_names or things will get messed up

Comment: When I tried using your code to assign to backup_ids, I just get "error on this line"
`BACKUP_NAMES=$(heroku pg:backups:schedules -a $APP_NAME | sed -n '1!p' | cut -f1 -d":")
BACKUP_IDS=$(heroku pg:backups -a $APP_NAME | grep -w -f <(echo "$BACKUP_NAMES"))`

Comment: There are two lines, not one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to assign an array to the list of backup IDs, how about:

```
for i in $(heroku pg:backups:schedules -a "$APP_NAME" | sed -n '1!p' | cut -f1 -d":"); do
    backup_ids+=($(heroku pg:backups -a "$APP_NAME" | grep -w "$i" | grep -o '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'))
done
echo "${backup_ids[@]}"
```

Output:

```
a555 a554
```

**[EDIT]**
If your `bash` does not support `+=` syntax, please try instead:

```
for i in $(heroku pg:backups:schedules -a "$APP_NAME" | sed -n '1!p' | cut -f1 -d":"); do
    backup_ids[j]=$(heroku pg:backups -a "$APP_NAME" | grep -w "$i" | grep -o '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]*')
    ((j+=1))
done
echo "${backup_ids[@]}"
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the second line, it seems to think the '+' is part of backup_ids variable name. If I put a space between it then it gives me an error of "backup_ids command not found." Other than that, this looks like it would work!

Comment: The `+=` assignment operator (append to the value of a string or array) has been supported since bash-3.1. Can you find which is your bash version with `bash --version`?